# Python module not found AWS lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, module

I am trying to import tldextract as follows in my lambda function

```
import tldextract
```

This gives me an error  `Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'tldextract'`

My python runtime is Python3.8

I know locally when I get this error i generally

```
 pip install module
```

But how do I achieve this with an AWS Lambda function?

Comment: Please refer one of these AWS Lambda deployment packaging ways - [Updating lambda with additional dependencies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-dependencies) or [Using a virtual environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-venv) or [Creating Lambda container images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html)

Answer (score 0):

To have custom libraries dependencies on your lambda you can pack the deployment dependencies that you need on the root folder of the lambda function, zip it and upload it. As explained here: [python-package-dependencies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-dependencies). Or you can upload the complete python virtual environment as well.

Another great option is to create a Lambda Layer, upload the dependencies that you need and later add the layer to your lambda function to import the libraries. The advantage of this option is that you can use these layers across multiple lambda functions while maintaining your deployment packages small.

You can find more details about lambda layers [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html).